# System.Memory support in Xamarin.Android for VS 2017

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

In a Xamarin Application I have used a third party library that references system.collection.Immutable. No issues were faced while building the application for Android in VS 2019.

When I tried to build the application in VS 2017 then it is showing the following build error

```
Error XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `System.Memory`, referenced by `System.Collections.Immutable`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Memory`, or remove the reference to `System.Collections.Immutable`.
```

After adding the reference to System.Memory the error is resolved.

Please let me know the actual reason behind this because the target android version(Android 9.0 pie) is the same for VS 2017 and VS 2019

Comment: use packages.config instead of **PackageReference Include**, I had similar issue with System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, which also causes wired errors with **PackageReference Include** and switching back to packages.config fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue appeared because the Xamarin SDK versions in Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019 have a tricky compatibility relationship with the System.Memory NuGet package versions. In Visual Studio 2019 , Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS use their own built-in implementations of the types from that NuGet package, so they don't need to reference the assembly from the NuGet package. The System.Memory NuGet package accordingly includes placeholder files for Xamarin project types to prevent conflicts.

But the built-in implementations do not yet cover the full surface area of the NuGet package. So for Visual Studio 2017, the Mono team temporarily hid those built-in implementations (by switching them to internal and removing the System.Memory facade assembly). This means that Xamarin projects now depend on the implementations from the NuGet package instead.

Comment: Thanks Leo, Is there any Microsoft referance for this.

Comment: @Manishkumar I'm sorry that I haven't found the explanation about this for the moment.